# how to determine anchor sizes for RetinaNet model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection

I am trying to implement a RetinaNet model in pytorch for my custom dataset, however, i am little confused on how some of the hyper-parameters are chosen. For example, the model uses anchor size of `[32, 64, 128, 256, 512]`, anchor ratio of `[0.5, 1, 2]` and anchor scale of `[1, 1.25, 1.58]`, but how do we determine these numbers for our own datasets. What are some of the ways we can go about when selecting param for the anchor box generation part ?

Answer (score 0):

The anchor ratio can be determined as ratio = bounding box height / bounding box width.
The scales factor is used to enlarge the basic feature map at an anchor. The ratios factor is used in the same way. So for each feature map a variety of different aspect ratios and sizes are used to try to match with the annotated bounding boxes of the target objects.

A good way to automatically obtain a list of optimized parameters is to use the Anchor Optimization repository by Martin Zlocha, Qi Dou and Ben Glocker. You can check it out to get an idea on how to automatize the process.

Link to it:
https://github.com/martinzlocha/anchor-optimization/